# How to Concatenate a username with their email address (contains their username)

Tags: string, tcl

I have a user "rbrown" and his email address variable "rbrownEmail"

I have a variable that contains "rbrown", but I want to concatenate the username variable $User (rbrown) so that it adds Email to the end so that it equals the variable "rbrownEmail"

So kind of like:

```
puts "Sending email to the following $User at email address: $($User+Email)
```

which would translate to:

```
 "Sending email to the following rbrown at email address $rbrownEmail
```

(which the variable contains his email address)

If that makes sense, I just don't know how to do that in TCL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% set User rbrown
rbrown
% set rbrownEmail foo@bar.baz
foo@bar.baz
% puts "Sending email to the following $User at email address: [set ${User}Email]"
Sending email to the following rbrown at email address: foo@bar.baz
```

You need to construct the variable name in one step (`${User}Email`) and get the variable's value in a second step (`[set ...]`). The braces around `User` are necessary to make it clear were the name ends and the string `Email` begins.

---

If you have control over how variables are named, it's easier to keep a piece of data which is essentially indexed by a variable value in an `array` or `dict` (both of which are associative structures).

For example:

```
set User rbrown
set email($User) foo@bar.baz

puts "Sending email to the following $User at email address: $email($User)"
```

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm)